# iphone app opens where stopped last time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, launch

When the app that I'm developing is launched, the user returns at the view that was open the last time before close. This seems to be normal behaviour. Can I turn this off to make sure that the user always starts with a login view ?

thanks for your advice 
Frank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably running on iOS >= 4.0. That is the default behavior. To disable is set `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to true on your Info.plist.

Answer (score 4):

As Felz pointed out, you can disable this easily. I would recommend though leaving it on and developing another solution. Users generally appreciate if the app reopens where they left it. Maybe they want to quickly look up something, maybe they simply get a phone call - when they come back, they don't want to reenter login information.

If your app displays secret information or something else that you don't want to be easily accessible, you could still implement a timer: When the app has been running in the background for some time, e.g. 5 minutes, and is reopened, you could display your login screen again.